# Account is being logged in Account Settings in user's device (Android)

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

We have an application does not directly interact with the Android framework AccountManager in any way.

The application authenticates with Salesforce by extending the provided OAuthWebviewHelper class. This class ends up calling the Salesforce SDK's ClientManager which calls AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly. This results in account details showing up in device system settings.

Is there is a way to avoid the app from accessing AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly which causes the issue.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way around this.  The account is automatically added by AccountManager.

Comment: Based on our observation the issue does not occur in lower android version but it appears in android 7.

Comment: I see it in every API version we support, the current minimum being API 21/Android 5.0.2.  It is handled by the Android SDK/OS, not App developers.